# How do I get whether it is user's favorite flag

Tags: android, sdk, deezer

I use the Deezer API to request selection and charts tracks, but there didn't return any flag used to identify whether the album or the track is favorited by the current user (for example with a `is_loved_track:true` or `is_favorite:true`).

So I can't judge to display "add to my favorite" or "remove from my favorite" from user inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can't know if a track or album is in a user's favorites from the charts requests. But you can make additional request when the user login to get the user's loved tracks (`http://api.deezer.com/user/{user_id}/tracks`) and favorite albums (`http://api.deezer.com/user/{user_id}/albums`) and then simply compare if a chart track / album appears in those lists.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of the user's loved tracks is too much,i can't get them in a request.So I should get them for several times? After I get all tracks,then compare if a chrat track in those lists?